# How to set layer symbol and layer name side by side in QGIS Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

When I add a legend in QGIS Composer, the layer symbols are set below each layer name. Is there any way to have them side by side?

This is what I get:

"LayerName"   [layer name]
~         [layer symbol]

This is what I need:

~ "LayerName"

Answer (score 1):

Select the legend. In the item properties - legend items, select the layer name and click the edit button. Delete the entire line. Then select the symbol and click the edit button. Enter the text you want to appear after the symbol.

*When you delete layer name, QGIS will adjust the legend to remove the blank line.